# How to allow a wide range of Rails versions for a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I'm the author of pretty simple [Rails engine gem](https://github.com/maxcal/pagescript) that basically just consists of a helper and a bit of javascript.

The only real runtime dependency is jquery-rails.

Hopefully it should pretty much be compatible with any Rails version > 5. As I originally wrote the gem I used a pragmatic squiggly arrow.

```
s.add_dependency 'rails', '~> 5.0.0', '>= 5.0.0.1'
```

Which was pretty foolish since it does not work with 5.1+. I now changed it to an open requirement `">= 5.0"` and `gem build` warns that its not advisable:

```
WARNING:  open-ended dependency on rails (>= 5.0) is not recommended
  if rails is semantically versioned, use:
    add_runtime_dependency 'rails', '~> 5.0'
```

Whats the best practice in terms of minimising maintenance and ensuring decent compatibility?

Should I declare the Rails dependency as a development_dependency since its implied that the gem is mounted in rails engine?

Comment: `s.add_dependency 'rails', '~> 5.0'` would allow anything `∈ [5.0, 6.0)`.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin I think that '~> 5.0' allow any number after last dot. So '5.0' - '5.999999' but not '6.0' .

Comment: @Foton I wrote precisely this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggestion in the warning is good advice.

`s.add_dependency 'rails', '~> 5.0'` This would mean it's fine for Rails 5.x, but not for 6.x.